# How to get dropdown instance value in WordPress custom Widget

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, widgets, terms

I am building a custom widget for my custom taxonomy and custom post type. basically it is a widget which displays recent posts from custom post type(game). I want to give the user an option to choose a term from which he want to display the custom posts. I have placed a drop-down list with all the custom terms available for my custom post type. But the problem is when user selects a term from the list, the drop-down instance  `$instance( cat_drop )` does not returne any value. what i will do is i will get this value and make a custom query to return all the posts from the selected term. following is my code.

```
    function get_all_terms(){
            $args = array(
                'taxonomy'           => 'gamecategory',
                'hide_empty'         => 0,
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'show_count'         => 0,
                'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
                'title_li'           => 0,
                'style'              => '',
                'echo'               => false,
            );
            $categories = wp_list_categories($args);
            if ( $categories ) {    
               // printf( '<div class="col">%s</div>', $categories );
            }
        return $categories;

        }

        /**
         * Adds Latest Games widget.
         */
        class latest_games_widget extends WP_Widget {

            /**
             * Register widget with WordPress.
             */
            function __construct() {
                parent::__construct(
                    'latest_games_widget', // Base ID
                    esc_html__( 'Latest Games', 'prisma' ), // Name
                    array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'Most Recent Games', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
                );
            }

            /**
             * Front-end display of widget.
             */
            public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
                echo $args['before_widget'];
                if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
                    echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
                }
                //Widget Content
                $selected_cat = $instance['cat_drop'];

                $args = array('post_type' => 'game', 'gamecategory' =>$selected_cat);
                $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                if($loop->have_posts(  )): 
                    while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();?>
                        <div class="col-md-3 game-card-outer">                   
                            <div class="game-card">
                                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small', array('class' => 'aligncenter'));  ?></a>
                                <?php endif;?>

                                <a class="latest_games_widget_post_title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                            </div>
                        </div>                                
                   <?php endwhile;
                endif;

                //After Widget part
                echo $args['after_widget'];
            }                

            /**
             * Back-end widget form.
             *
             * @see WP_Widget::form()
             *
             * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
             */
            public function form( $instance ) {
                $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( '', 'prisma' );
                $cat_title = ! empty( $instance['cat_title'] ) ? $instance['cat_title'] : esc_html__( '', 'prisma' );
                ?>
                <select name="" id="<?php echo ( $this->get_field_id( 'cat_drop' ) ); ?>">
                            <?php $terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'gamecategory','hide_empty' => false,]);foreach($terms as $item){?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $item->name;?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?></option>
                                <?php }?>
</select>        
                <p>
                <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'cat_title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Game category to Display:', 'prisma' ); ?></label> 
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'cat_title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'cat_title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
                </p>                
                <p>
                <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Widget Title:', 'prisma' ); ?></label> 
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
                </p>                                                        
                <?php 
            }                                                
            /**
             * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
             *
             * @see WP_Widget::update()
             *
             * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
             * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
             *
             * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
             */
            public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
                $instance = array();
                $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
                $instance['cat_title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['cat_title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['cat_title'] ) : '';
    $instance[ 'cat_drop' ] = ( !empty( $new_instance[ 'cat_drop' ] ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'cat_drop' ] ) :  esc_html__('','prisma') );

                return $instance;
            }

        } // class Foo_Widget        

        // register Foo_Widget widget
        function register_foo_widget() {
            register_widget( 'latest_games_widget' );
        }
        add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_foo_widget' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cat_drop` setting is empty because your drop-down menu, or the `select` field doesn't have the proper `name` value, so PHP isn't receiving the selected option/value. So to fix the issue, just add the proper `name` value to the `select` field:

```html
<!-- Wrapped for brevity. -->
<select
  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cat_drop' ); ?>"
  id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cat_drop' ); ?>"
>
```

But then, there are **other issues in your code**:

1. In the `cat_drop` drop-down menu, the options should be the term *slug*, but you currently set it to the term *name*. So be sure to use the term slug instead:

   ```html
   <!-- Note the $item->slug -->
   <option value="<?php echo $item->slug;?>"><?php echo esc_html( $item->name ); ?></option>
   ```
2. In the widget *display* callback (`widget()`), you're overriding the `$args` variable when you do `$args = array('post_type' => 'game', 'gamecategory' =>$selected_cat);` and that results in a PHP notice with the `echo $args['after_widget'];` at the end of the function, because the `$args['after_widget']` is now undefined. And when it's undefined, the widget container will not be closed and that could result in layout issues, despite browsers are basically "smart" and would-auto close the container.

   So you should rename one of the `$args`, maybe the one that you use with `WP_Query`.
3. Using `esc_html__()` on an empty string is pointless: `esc_html__( '', 'prisma' )`. So change those to just `''`.
4. *This is just a personal note..* Could you please, improve the formatting of your code? E.g. Get rid of those unnecessary *blank lines* and use tab for indentation. Because a good code is not just one that works, but also clean because it would be easy for other developers to maintain or work with the code. :)